# jquery multipledatespicker returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am currently using a plugin called [multipledatespicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#option-mode) that are derived from the jquery UI, i've gotten most of my calender setting right, just that i'm not sure how should i return the value into a input box from the inline block calender.

```html
<div class="iDate"></div>
<input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="" />
```

```js
var unavailableDates = ["9-7-2016"];
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1)
        return [true, ""];
    else
        return [false, "denied", "Unavailable"];
}

var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(".iDate").multiDatesPicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: dateToday,
});

var dates = multiDatesPicker('value');
document.getElementById('something').value = dates;
```

how can i show the multiple selected values of iDate into the input box "something" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your multiple date picker to the input box instead of the div then you you will get multiple comma separated dates in that input box after selecting a date. You can make input box readonly so no one can manually edit the dates selected.

Alternatively you can use datepicker's on select event to put the values into hidden elements or js arrays etc.

Example:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(".iDate").multiDatesPicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(date) {
       AddDate(date);
    }
});

//pseudo code -> have no time at work...
 create mydates object // array that holds selected dates


function AddDate(value) {     
    //warning pseudo code
    if value in mydates -> remove it for mydates
    else -> add value to mydates

}
```